# my .htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the rules:

```
#RULE REDIRECTQUESTIONSURL9 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^scid=9
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} questions.php
RewriteRule ^questions\.php$ /general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-0 [R,L,QSD]
```

These types of links are not working

```
> http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=6
> http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=8
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that immediately come to mind when looking at your rewrite rules.

1. `scid=9` is looking for the static value `9`. Neither of shown URLs have that value.
2. `!^POST$` the URL you're showing is making a `GET` request.

Give this a try:

```
    #RULE REDIRECTQUESTIONSURL9 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^GET$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^scid=\d+
    RewriteRule ^questions\.php$ /general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-0 [R,L,QSD]
```

Also do you care about the parameter coming from the query string? If not you could just take that requirement off. If so you should capture it and append it to the rewritten URL.

You should change your links to

```
action="general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-<?php echo $id;?>"
```

or

```
href="general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-<?php echo $id;?>"
```

then have your htaccess work the opposite way. The rewrite rewrites the request on the backend; the frontend URL stays the same.

So

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^GET$
RewriteRule ^general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-(\d+)  questions.php?scid=$1
```

Comment: Is it a POST or GET request? Are you using a form with method post? Also the `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} questions.php` isn't needed the `RewriteRule` has the page already in it.

Comment: Your `htaccess` has soo many rules. It should be more dynamic. Your PHP script is open to SQL injections. I can't go through that much PHP, is the page being loaded as a GET or POST?

Comment: http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=6  http://www.example.com/questions.php?scid=8  these types of links are not appearing as user friendly as done in htaccess.

Comment: The page is loaded as GET Method

Comment: Oh, sorry, you want to go the other way. Make the links `/general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-0`. then the rewrite `general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-(\d+)` and send that to `questions.php?scid=$1`.

Comment: how to make links like /general-knowledge_questions-answers_national-famous-day-0 and please tell me the code for htaccess

Comment: I have done what you said.  but it is still not working